# Duplicate record in database when call SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework

Hi i have a problem with EF. In my application i have to load from database some content to populate a `DataGrid`.

UserControl :

```
 contenus = new List<Contenu>();
        contenus = sacoche.Contenus.ToList(); // i get sacoche in the parameter of the contructor
        ContenuViewSource.Source = contenus;
        ContenuView = (ListCollectionView)ContenuViewSource.View;
        ContenuView.Refresh();
```

everything work just fine, but when i try to add some others Contenus i get a duplicate record in the database. The only difference between the duplicated record is that the first record loose his foreign key.

Here i add my `Contenu`to my `Sacoche`:

```
editableSacoche = SacocheDal.dbContext.Sacoches.Include("Contenus").First(i => i.SacocheID == editableSacoche.SacocheID);
            editableSacoche.Contenus = contenus;
            SacocheDal.dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

all i do is get the `Sacoche` and add to it his `Contenu` and finally call `SaveChanges()`.

Here is the result :
    [image: problem duplicate]

EDIT: I tried to get only the new items but failed.

```
List<Contenu> contenuAjoute = contenus.Except(editableSacoche.Contenus.ToList()).ToList();
```

in `contenuAjoute`i get all the records even if they are equal ...

Comment: ensure you have the key for `Contenus` on `editableSacoche` as `ContenusID`.

Comment: Can you tell me more about your comment please

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: I can't figure it out, can you please provide a piece of code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve what i wanted. I create an `ItemComparer` and use `Except`to only add the new items.

Here is the comparer :

```
 class ContenuComparer : IEqualityComparer<Contenu>
{
    public bool Equals(Contenu x, Contenu y)
    {
        if (x.ContenuID == y.ContenuID)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Contenu obj)
    {
        return obj.ContenuID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And Here the code :

```
editableSacoche = SacocheDal.dbContext.Sacoches.Include("Contenus").First(i => i.SacocheID == editableSacoche.SacocheID);
            List<Contenu> contenuAjoute = contenus.Except(editableSacoche.Contenus.ToList(), new ContenuComparer()).ToList();
            foreach (Contenu c in contenuAjoute)
            {
                editableSacoche.Contenus.Add(c);
            }
            SacocheDal.dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I don't now if it's the right way but it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
editableSacoche = SacocheDal.dbContext.Sacoches.Include("Contenus").First(i => i.SacocheID == editableSacoche.SacocheID);
editableSacoche.Contenus = null;
            editableSacoche.ContenusID = contenus.ID;
            SacocheDal.dbContext.SaveChanges();
```